# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime, Jul 11, 2019

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion

I have a string that's coming from a Griview Cell. The value of this string is `Jul 11, 2019`. I need to convert this into `yyyy-MM-dd` format, but upon trying to convert I am getting an error.

So far I have tried the following:

- `DateTime.ParaExact(Startdatebefore, "yyyy-MM-dd",Null)`
- `String.Convert("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Here's a code sample for context:

```
string Startdatebefore = item.Cells[4].Text;
string StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Startdatebefore, "yyyy-MM-dd", null).ToString();
---- // The second way of trying to convert is below and this also is not working. 
DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Cells[4].Text);
string EndDatedone = EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But I'm still getting an error.

Where am I making a mistake? I reviewed a lot of questions on Stack and google, but most of them are in number date format before and do not match the error I have. Please let me know if you have any idea on why this is going wrong.

Comment: Why do all your mask attempts have the year at the beginning when that is clearly not what your input string has?

Comment: The parse format needs to match the format of the initial string, not the format you want to convert to. Try `MMM dd, yyyy`

Comment: What is the actual value in the cell you are trying to convert?  Debug and find that first.  Could have spaces or something else, or not even what you think is in there

Comment: Please show an actual string value when assigning `Startdatebefore`, instead of `item.Cells[4].Text`, so we're all on the same page.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact doesn't reformat one string into a different string. It takes a string of the specified format -- you're giving it "MMM dd, yyyy" -- and returns a `DateTime` *object* which has no particular format at all. `DateTime` has an integer property called Year, an integer property called Month, another called Day, etc. etc right down to milliseconds. Once you've got that datetime object, you can take that and convert *it* into a string in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, using `resultingDateTime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the info, yes that was the mistake I was trying to convert but forgot that its just a data collection call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//get the string
string Startdatebefore = item.Cells[4].Text;
// Parse to DateTime using the original **source** format:
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Startdatebefore, "MMM dd, yyyy", null);
// create the string from the DateTime using the **target** format
Startdatebefore = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Or in a single line:

```
string Startdatebefore = DateTime.ParseExact(Startdatebefore, "MMM dd, yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

A final note: if you're doing this for inclusion in an SQL statement, you're doing something **VERY** wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot the  one line string format and collection worked perfect, I am not working with SQL, I simply need this data from a asp.net gridview to put into a CSV file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The string 'Jul 11, 2019' should parse just fine through the normal DateTime parser. You can then give your desired format to DateTime's ToString method.

```
var formatted = DateTime.Parse("Jul 11, 2019").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine(formatted); // 2019-07-11
```